# saveToCassandra saving the whole table instead of a single row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a cassandra keyspace and table that I am querying data from in order to write to another keyspace/table.  My code is as follows:

```
val test = sc.cassandraTable("model","data")
.where("id = 9999999")
.select("id","cl1","cl2","data")
.filter(row => row.getString("data") == "Hello")


test.saveToCassandra("model","dataspark",SomeColumns("id","cl1","cl2","data"))
```

The problem is for some reason it is writing everything that is in model.data into model.dataspark INSTEAD of just what I have specified in my val test variable.  I must have some syntax or something wrong.

If I `.collect` and do a `.foreach(println)`  it shows only the single entry that Im querying as expected.  My saveToCassandra statement must be wrong but I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

I tried the whole thing with a case class and same result:

```
case class Record(id: Int, cl1: Int, cl2: Int, data: Option[String])
val test = sc.cassandraTable[Record]("model","data")
.where("id = 9999999").select("id","cl1","cl2","data")
test.saveToCassandra("model","dataspark", SomeColumns("id","cl1","cl2","data"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

```
val test = sc.cassandraTable("model","data")
.where("id = 9999999")
```

Needs to all be on the same line

```
val test = sc.cassandraTable("model","data").where("id = 9999999")
```

Comment: in my code spark i.e SparkSession does not have cassandraTable or saveToCassandra methods ...how should i get it ? I am using spark-sql v2.3.1 for writing data into cassandra v3.11.1 and i already added spark-cassandra-connector and cassandra-driver-core jars in my classpath